# cookie showing previus data call value in PHP

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies

I an sending soap request and storing the response i need in variable, then i am storing it in a cookie. but when i print them both i am getting in cookie value of the previous response call:

```
$login_token = $asArray['soap:Envelope']['soap:Body']['LoginResponse']['LoginResult'];
setcookie("login_token_cookie", $login_token,time()+60*60*24*30);

print_r ($login_token);
echo "</br>";
echo $_COOKIE["login_token_cookie"];
```

I tried to delete the cookie by using setcookie() on yesterday date but it didn't help.
any ideas?

Comment: You need to re-navigate to the page to see changes to see new cookie values (remember how HTTP Cookies work?).

Comment: Yes - I have Noted that I cannot set a cookie in PHP and hope to retrieve the cookie immediately in that same script session.

But i need somehow to use cookies in the same script, i need to pass them trough several soap calls.

In Java, something called session_maintain_property is used which allows for the program to use cookies

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload the page in order for the new cookie to be set.

try:

```
$_COOKIE["login_token_cookie"] = $login_token;
setcookie("login_token_cookie", $login_token,time()+60*60*24*30);
```

Comment: it looks like it took care of the problem, 10x

Comment: when i use $_COOKIE["login_token_cookie"] = $login_token
then it will be like a regular variable, and i need it to use the actual cookie.
I need to be able to store the soap response (login token) into a cookie and the use it in a different soap call.

Comment: Then you can force a reload of the page in order for the browser to send the cookie in it's headers towards your server.

Answer (score 0):

In your setcookie() function use time which is previous to current time.

```
setcookie("login_token_cookie", $login_token,time()-10);
```

Comment: if i will use the sugested the it will delete the cookie and i will not be able to use it.
I need to be able to store the soap response (login token) into a cookie and the use it in a different soap call

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved.
the issue was with the SoapClient, when i was sending a request i created a new SoapClient for every call and that gave me a different cookies per each call - kind of a different session.